# VS Code issue with interpreter selector not showing (Python with image)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I have had it working previously but not sure what I did to remove it or delete it possibly. I can't see the python environment selector anymore in VS Code for Python, I am almost certain it is the source for many other issues I am experiencing. I have the Python extension installed and Python installed as well, I have tried reinstalling different Python versions and reinstalling the Python extension in VS Code.

I've included pictures to make it clear what is missing, thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most recent update, they moved it to the right hand side of the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Install python extension by Microsoft in vscode then check if it's not working install pylance too.

Comment: Yep have both of those installed already and enabled

Comment: Check on your right side where your language is shown(python)